# Impact on landing with forward motion vs straight down

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, everyday-life, collision

A skateboarder ollies down a set of stair. Is the impact when landing less than if dropped straight down from the same height?

Answer (score 0):

If you take the **exact** moment the wheels hit the ground, before the board moves forward, there is no difference between dropping straight down and coming in at say 45 degrees. This is no big deal dropping from a metre, but from a greater height, your body may not be able to absorb the impact without damage, before you transfer your  potential energy into safer horizontal kinetic energy.